# android parsing negative number strings

Tags: java, string, parsing, negative-number

How to parse negative number strings?

strings may be of the form:

```
-123.23  
(123.23)  
123.23-
```

is there a class that will convert any of the above strings to a number?

if not, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is there the possibility of (-123.12) or (123.12-) ?

Comment: how do you treat?
(-123.12) or (123.12-)
are they parsed as double negative, hence positive?

Comment: yes, negative numbers (in financial stuff) can be represented as follows:
-123.23
(123.23)
123.23-
i've seen europeans wrote it as <123.23>
checkout libreoffice calc, it'll take all of the above cheerfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on WarrenFaiths answer you can add this:

```
Double newNumber = 0;
if(number.charAt(i).isDigit()){
     //parse numeber here using WarrenFaiths method and place the int or float or double 
     newNumber = Double.valueOf(number);
}else{
    Boolean negative = false;

    if(number.startsWith("-") || number.endsWith("-")){
         number = number.replace("-", "");
         negative = true;
    }
    if(number.startsWith("(") || number.endsWith(")"){
        number = number.replace("(", "");
        number = number.replace(")", "");
    }

    //parse numeber here using WarrenFaiths method and place the float or double 
    newNumber = Double.valueOf(number);

    if(negative){
      newNumber = newNumber * -1;
    }
}
```

Im sorry if the replace methods are wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Instead of contains, I would use startsWith and endsWith.

Comment: Yeah less computation I'll add that in.

Comment: I would suggest a more bullet proof way: just accept digits, +/- and the ./, symbols and throw away everything else. So using `numberString.charAt(i).isDigit()` could be a start :). Regular expressions could eliminate the non used chars, too.

Comment: We can complicate it more if we want :P, Regex doesn't seem like something this person wants to use quite yet, this should work for him :)

Comment: was hoping there is an universal class out there to tackle this, java being used by big corp and negative numbers in parentheses or postfix negative sign are in use. regex and if statements will have to do. thanks much.

Comment: If there are parens, then it is negative in the accounting world so negative needs to be set to true.

Answer (score 4):

`"-123.23"` can be parsed with `Float.valueOf("-123.23");` or `Double.valueOf("-123.23");`

`"(123.23)"` and `"123.23-"` are invalid and need to be improved/parsed by yourself. You could go through the string step by step and check if it is a number, if so add it to a new string. If you find a - at the beginning or the end, make it than negative...

Comment: Built on your comment above :D

Comment: here's the hack, pls comment on improvements etc, time to learn some more myself :)

Answer (score 0):

here's the hack, pls comment on improvements etc, time to learn some more myself :)

```
private Double RegNumber(String sIn) {
        Double result = 0E0;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\-?([0-9]{0,3}(\\,?[0-9]{3})*(\\.?[0-9]*))");   // -1,123.11
        Matcher m = p.matcher(sIn);
        if (m.matches()) {
            result = Double.valueOf(sIn);
        } else {
            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^\\(?([0-9]{0,3}(\\,?[0-9]{3})*(\\.?[0-9]*))\\)?$");  // (1,123.22)
            Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(sIn);
            if (m1.matches()) {
                String x[] = sIn.split("(\\({1})|(\\){1})"); // extract number
                result = Double.valueOf("-" + x[1]);
            } else {
                Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{0,3}(\\,?[0-9]{3})*(\\.?[0-9]*))\\-$");  // 1,123.22-
                Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(sIn);
                if (m2.matches()) {
                    String x[] = sIn.split("(\\-{1})"); // extract number
                    result = Double.valueOf("-" + x[0]);
                } else {
                    result = 99999999E99;  // error, big value
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```